# NPM RUN deploy gives an error message. Failed at RoboFriends deploy Script. "There is likely additional logging out put above"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, github-pages

So i just created a React app and when trying to deploy it, i get the following error.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlRPA.jpg)

This is my package.JSON file:-

`{
  "name": "robofriends",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://paarth1995.github.io/RoboFriends",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5",
    "tachyons": "^4.11.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^2.0.0"
  }
}`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's maybe related to your git global configurations. 

please check that your email is presented in

```
git config -l
```

and check that the property "user.email" is filled with your email.

if there is no user.email property, use this command to set it.

```
git config --global user.email "email@example.com"
```

Comment: I did a git config -l but i do not see any user.email property. Should i manually add that in there?